# Cast JSONArray item to JSONObject - ClassCastException

Tags: java, json, classcastexception, org.json

I  try to process JSON response with help of "org.json" library. So, I convert string response to JSONArray:

```
JSONArray listWallPosts = jsonWallPosts.getJSONArray("response");
```

and listWallPosts contains for example such data set:

```
[1388,
{
    "date": 1441127306,
    "from_id": 45700,
    "comments": {
        "count": 0,
        "can_post": 1
    },
    "to_id": 44970,
    "online": 0,
    "post_type": "post",
    "id": 2469,
    "text": "Some message",
    "reply_count": 0
},
{
    "date": 1425812975,
    "from_id": 16089771,
    "comments": {
        "count": 0,
        "can_post": 1
    },
    "to_id": 44970,
    "online": 0,
    "post_type": "post",
    "id": 2467,
    "text": "Some another message",
    "reply_count": 0,
}]
```

When I try to process list items in loop:

```
for(int j=0; j< listWallPosts.length(); j++){
    JSONObject post = (JSONObject)listWallPosts.get(j);
    //do something
}
```

I face with **ClassCastException -- java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject**.

Can someone suggest best approach to handle it? Should I wrap casting from list item to JSONObject in try-catch or are there better options?

Comment: If there's a number in the json array, retrieve it as a number. What don't you understand about the error given the json you provided?

Comment: I understand cause of exception, but I ask "about better approach to handle it", not why it happens!

Comment: @Rustam, it's part of response, and I'm not sure what it's exactly.. Possible, number of items in response.

Comment: What is your current approach for handling it? Why do you think it's bad?

Comment: can you try `(JSONObject)listWallPosts.getJSONObject(j);`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I wrap **JSONObject post = (JSONObject)listWallPosts.get(j);** in **if(listWallPosts.get(j) instanceof JSONObject){...}**. What do you think, is it good way? or we can validate it  better?

Comment: The `org.json.JSONArray` doesn't give you much choice. You need to retrieve the value and then check for its type. Gson and Jackson give you much more functionality for checking the type of the values inside a JSON array.

Comment: @Rustam, look better on my question, I'm using casting to JSONObject

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I will look on Gson and Jackson, thanks! can you post it as an answer? I could vote for it

Comment: I don't want to go into detail. [Here's](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#get-int-) Jackson's `ArrayNode` type which represents a JSON array. Its `get(int)` method returns a `JsonNode` which you can then query to check its type with the various `isXyz` methods.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my current approach I handle it with **instanceof** in **if** statement:

```
for(int j=0; j< listWallPosts.length(); j++){
    if(listWallPosts.get(j) instanceof JSONObject){
        JSONObject post = (JSONObject)listWallPosts.get(j);
        //to do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I chose this approach because in contrast to the solution, which KDM suggested, this code works in case when any list element can be not a JSONObject (e.g. number).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your response has some sort of `ID` and a list of `JSONObject`s associated with it. You may have to code somewhat like this:

```
int id = listWallPosts.getInt(0);
for(int j = 1; j < listWallPosts.length(); j++) {
    JSONObject post = listWallPosts.getJSONObject(j);
}
```